# Copy the date text to textfield using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to copy the date text to textfield. when i click the button to copy, the result in textfield is undefined. Can someone help me about this problem?

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {

  var date1 = document.getElementById("datetime");
  var text1 = document.getElementById("textfield1");

  text1.value = date1.value;
}

var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
```

```html
<p name="datetime" id="datetime" style="position:absolute;margin-top:80px;font-weight:bold"><span id="datetime" name="datetime" id="date_now"></span></p>

<input type="text" id="textfield1" name="textfield1">

<input type="submit" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" value="copy">
```

Comment: first of all change the input type of button to button and not submit because your function runs on onClick and not onSubmit.

Comment: @DhavalChheda—while that is technically correct, it doesn't affect the the execution of the function since the button is not in a form, so nothing to submit. ;-)

Comment: @RobG how will the ShowHideDiv() function be invoked?

Comment: Note that *toISOString* returns a date string based on UTC, so the date will appear to be wrong for the period of the timezone offset.

Comment: @DhavalChheda—by clicking on the button.

Comment: There are other issues with your code. Don't give names to elements that aren't form controls (they should be accessed by ID, not name), and don't give the same element two different IDs (the span has ids *datetime* and *date_now*).

Comment: @RobG so you are saying that even if the input if of type="submit" and if I have an onClick event then it will fire on the click ? and if Yes then what will happen if I had an onSubmit event also defined ?

Comment: @DhavalChheda—yes, the onclick handler will be called if you click on the button, regardless of its type. Submit listeners are only relevant to a form, they have no effect on a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the date as innerHTML of the paragraph tag. So, instead of `date1.value` use `date1.innerHTML`. Check the working snippet:

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {

  var date1 = document.getElementById("datetime");
  var text1 = document.getElementById("textfield1");

  text1.value = date1.innerHTML;
}

var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
```

```html
<p name="datetime" id="datetime" style="position:absolute;margin-top:80px;font-weight:bold"><span id="datetime" name="datetime" id="date_now"></span></p>

<input type="text" id="textfield1" name="textfield1">

<input type="submit" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" value="copy">
```

Comment: Ive got it now!! Thank you so much for your help.. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `innerHTML` which will provide the inner content of selected element by id.

```
function ShowHideDiv() {
        var date1 = document.getElementById("datetime");
        var text1 = document.getElementById("textfield1"); 
        text1.value =  date1.innerHTML;
    }
    var dt = new Date();document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
```

> The [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element.

Also you need to use `button` instead of using input with type submit, since you are not submitting the data. This approach will be more fast and better.

```
<button type="button" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" >Copy</button>
```